# server multithreading can't save last socket descriptor

Tags: c++, multithreading, server, client

I have a project in which we are using threads. 
Problem is, every time a specific client sends a message, it saves only the LAST client_sock that was made, and that way I can't save the previous thread's call because every message I send from any client it answers me the answer of the last client that was created, means previous clients are ran over.

```
class ServerTcp {
private:
pthread_t threads[50];
```

This is the function creating the threads, which is sending to recieveAndSend:

```
void ServerTcp:: acceptTheReaquest(){
struct sockaddr_in client_sin;
unsigned int addr_len = sizeof(client_sin);
int sockFd;
while((sockFd = accept(this->sock,  (struct sockaddr *) &client_sin,  
&addr_len)) >= 0){
     struct arg_struct args; //has only 2 values, initialized in next lines
     args.client_sock = sockFd;
     args.server = this;
     cout << "created " << sockFd << endl;
    pthread_create(&threads[numOfThreads],NULL,
    &ServerTcp::recieveAndSend, &args);
    numOfThreads++;
}
}
```

this is the function receiveAndSend:

```
static void* ServerTcp:: recieveAndSend(void * args){
arg_struct* arguments = static_cast<arg_struct*>(args);
char buffer[4096];
while (true){
    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    int bytes = arguments->server->recieveFromClient(buffer,
     arguments->client_sock);
    if (bytes >0){
        string message = arguments->server->reciveOutput(buffer);
        arguments->server->sendTO(message, arguments->client_sock);
    }
}
return (void*)NULL;
}
```

this is the function sendTo:

```
void ServerTcp:: sendTO(string answer, int client_sock){
cout << "sending to " << client_sock << endl;
char buffer[4096];
strcpy(buffer, answer.c_str());
this->sent_bytes = send(client_sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
}
```

output:

```
created 4
received from 4
created 5
received from 5
```

this means I've created a thread for client_sock 4 , and wait to receive from client_sock 4, and same for client_sock 5. now I want the server to print sending to 4, received from 4 - because I used the client with client_sock 4 which is the first one created, and the one I sent the message from, but it still holds client_sock 5, and output is:

```
sending to 5
received from 5
```

instead of

```
sending to 4
received from 4
```

.....HELP??

Comment: `memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));` just warms up the universe. Remove it from there and fight global warming!

Comment: Also, consider swithing to std::thread.

Answer (score 1):

The bug in your code is as follows (I have removed the irrelevant lines of code, and cleaned up the indentation):

```
while((sockFd = accept(this->sock,  (struct sockaddr *) &client_sin, &addr_len)) >= 0)
{
     struct arg_struct args;
     args.client_sock = sockFd;
     args.server = this;

     pthread_create(&threads[numOfThreads],NULL,
                    &ServerTcp::recieveAndSend, &args);
     numOfThreads++;
}
```

You are instantiating `arg_struct` in local scope, on the stack. You are then passing a pointer to the `arg_struct` to the new thread.

The problem here is that after pthread_create() returns in the parent thread, the loop terminates (well, the current iteration of the loop terminates, and it starts again), and the `arg_struct` is no longer valid.

However, the child thread will attempt to access it independently, via the pointer it received from pthread_create(), which will result in undefined behavior.

The behavior you've observed is the result of this undefined behavior (the parent thread will instantiate a new `arg_struct` on the stack, in the same raw memory location, for the second thread, but the first thread will still look in the same location, when it wakes up).

What you need to do is construct `arg_struct` on the heap, using the `new` operator. This way, the instantiated `arg_struct` will continue to exist, for the new thread. Of course, the new thread is responsible for `delete`ing the `arg_struct`, when its done, to avoid leaking memory.